# How to connect button in ios6 to LINEA Pro 4 barcode scanner

Tags: ios6, barcode-scanner, linea-pro

[How do I use the Linea-Pro SDK for IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935378/how-do-i-use-the-linea-pro-sdk-for-ios?answertab=active#tab-top)

I found the above, which got me to get a "connected". Thank you for that post, I was totally dead in the water until I found that post.

I'm now searching for the how-to to connect a button and also the scanners button to do a scan and then feed a textField. It's the connecting the button(s) that I'm having a hard time with. I'm pretty green to Xcode learning mostly by adapting examples.

I'm still searching through the LINEA SDK but it is quite overwhelming as it's all encompassing. I only want the barcode scanning feature.

I'm using minimum storyboard based project and just a button and textField to learn before adding the scanner to my real app.

Comment: Got it working. Now I just have to backtrack to figure out the how.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I use the Linea-Pro SDK for IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935378/how-do-i-use-the-linea-pro-sdk-for-ios)
Check this
Try their demo first which you can find here
http://www.datecs.bg/en/products/Linea-Pro-iPhone-SDK/8/102
that should help you.