# Linea Pro SDK doesn't display barcode

Tags: objective-c, linea-pro

I am using Linea Pro scanner to scan barcode. In my app, I have connected to the device, and start/stop scan.

However the barcodeData function doesn't seem to be triggered. it doesn't show anything in my label

```
-(void)barcodeData:(NSString *)barcode isotype:(NSString *)isotype
   {
    //display barcode
    self.lblbarcode.text=barcode;

   }
```

I took the advice from the following post

[How do I use the Linea-Pro SDK for IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935378/how-do-i-use-the-linea-pro-sdk-for-ios/14176506#14176506)

Please help

Thanks very much

Comment: You say it "doesn't seem to be triggered". Is it or isn't it? Put a breakpoint in the method and see if it is called or not.

Answer (score 1):

The function i use is wrong

```
-(void)barcodeData:(NSString *)barcode type:(int)type
  {
   //display barcode
   self.lblbarcode.text=barcode;

  }
```

is the correct one. Although the function in the original post is in the given example demo